# Spring @Service Concurency

Tags: spring-boot

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class BookingServiceImpl implements BookingService {

    private final AirTicketService airTicketService ;

  
    @Autowired
    public BookingServiceImpl (AirTicketService airTicketService) {
        this.airTicketService = airTicketService;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public boolean bookTicket(Customer customer) {
            return this.airTicketService.reserve(customer);
    }
}
```

If 10 threads are calling the bookTicket(Customer customer) method of BookingServiceImpl class with brand new customer object each time, then is there any chances of thread interference to be happened and the customer object will be poisoned by singleton beans of BookingService  and AirTicketService ?

Comment: you'd better edit your code and also add reserve method codes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not clear and I don't understand exactly what you mean by "be poisoned". You can take a look at this link to know about the multi-threads calling service class:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-singleton-concurrent-requests

If 10 threads call `bookTicket` method, then `airTicketService` object is shared between them, and they call `reserve` method with brand-new customer objects. I think you'd better consider the `reserve` method to find out what would happen to the customer objects. If reserve doesn't have anything to do with shared objects (let's say across the `AirTicketService` class), threads would probably modify the customer objects which are different for each thread.